# DataSet merge + sort not working

Tags: c#, sorting, dataset, dataview

I am having trouble sorting a dataset that is merged in the wrong order. Here is the code:

```
// Adding new data to DataSet ds:
DataSet dsNew = messageSearcher.Seek(_CriteriaCollection.ToString(), mb.ConvertedClassId, mb.ConnectionString); // Recieving a set of ID that are new and need to be added to ds
ds.Merge(dsNew);
// The data set is now sorted wrongly. Therefore want to sort it based on "MME_ID"        
var table = ds.Tables[0];
var view = new DataView(table);
var newRows = view.DeepCopy();
newRows.Sort = "MME_ID DESC"; // <--- This does not sort the ResultSet... Why?
table.Rows.Clear();
foreach (var row in newRows)
    table.Rows.Add(row);
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a view, `DataView.Sort` will not sort the underlying `DataTable`. I would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataSet` instead which is more readable and maintainable:

```
var table = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<int>("MME_ID"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that i've presumed that `MME_ID` is an `int` column. This throws an exception if its a different type like string. Then you eother have to change the `Field<T>` to use the proper type or - if you want to order numerically instead of lexicographically - parse it to `int` with `int.Parse`.